# Init scripts invoking script on a user's directory -- not working (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, init-script, sysvinit

I want to automatically start email tunnels and socks proxy at boot time.  I have an `/etc/init.d/email-tunnels` script that invokes another script under my home directory.  It won't work at boot time, it won't work if I execute `sudo service email-tunnels start`, but it does work if I just run it, `sudo /etc/init.d/email-tunnels start`.  BTW, I have an identical setup on another machine (Debian 8), and it works like a charm on that one.

These are the details (of the Ubuntu 18 setup, the one that is not working):

```
[···]$ ls -lh /etc/init.d/email-tunnels 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 602 Aug 28 10:21 /etc/init.d/email-tunnels
[···]$
```

The contents is (including some debugging `echo`s):

```
[···]$ cat /etc/init.d/email-tunnels 
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:     email_tunnels
# Required-Start:   $all
# Required-Stop:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:    2 3
# Default-Stop:     0 1 6
# Short-Description:    E-mail and HTTP tunnels over SSH
### END INIT INFO

echo "email-tunnels invoked at `date`" >> /tmp/email-tunnels.log

touch /var/lock/email-tunnels

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "email-tunnels executing 'start' at `date`" >> /tmp/email-tunnels.log
    su -c "/home/cal/bin/email.sh &" cal
    ;;
  stop)
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init/email-tunnels {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

And then, my script on my home directory:

```
[···]$ ls -lh /home/cal/bin/email.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cal cal 410 Aug 28 10:09 /home/cal/bin/email.sh
[···]$
```

And its contents:

```
[···]$ cat /home/cal/bin/email.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo "email.sh executed at `date`" >> /tmp/email.log
sleep 30

while [ "1" == "1" ]
do
    echo "email.sh about to execute ssh at `date`" >> /tmp/email.log
    ssh -N -D5080 -Llocalhost:10110:xx.xx.xx.xx:110 -Llocalhost:10025:xx.xx.xx.xx:25 tunnels@xx.xx.xx.xx
    sleep 120
done
```

The tunnels user on my target (server) machine does have the PK authentication properly configured, so that I can ssh-connect without any user interaction (without having to supply a password).

Any ideas why it's not working?  From the debugging output, I see that the init.d script (email-tunnels) is executed (I see the output at /tmp/email-tunnels.log), but not the /home/cal/bin/email.sh --- when I manually run `/etc/init.d/email-tunnels start`, then I do see the /tmp/email.log debugging output, and for that matter the tunnels work after I ran it.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this is a daemon with `/etc/init.d/` scripts rather than just having a cron job for that user scheduled to run `@reboot`?

Comment: Then continue using Debian, and forget ubuntu.

Comment: The `@reboot` feature seems a bit unreliable (e.g., https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root).  Plus, familiarity would also be a reason  (I feel --- or maybe I should say *felt* --- more comfortable with handling the init.d scripts to do what needs to be done after a reboot)

Comment: @IporSircer --- hahaha, good point!  I actually did adopt that position a couple of years ago;  however, for *desktop* machines, I still haven't crossed the threshold of feeling comfortable enough with Debian.  *All* of my non-GUI machines are now Debian.  Notice, however, that we're not talking about the same underlying Debian version  (my gateway machine at home, where the email-tunnels setup works, is Debian 8;  Ubuntu 18, where I'm so far unable to make it work, is based on a Debain two versions later!)

Answer (score 3):

You are using Ubuntu Linux, an operating system that has been a systemd operating system since 2016 and was an Upstart operating system for a decade before that, since 2006.  van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts are not the way, especially for new stuff.

And especially in this case.  This is almost a candidate for the *House of Horror*.  On your system a generated service unit is running a process to interpret a script, that forks a process to run `su` (abusing that to drop privileges), that forks a process to run a shell, that forks a process to interpret another script, that runs an infinite loop  Poor Man's Dæmon Supervisor that repeatedly forks `ssh`.

And all this just to do what a service manager can do *anyway*: run a specific program as a specific user and restart it every time that it exits.

Learn `journalctl -b` for reading the logs, and build upon this fairly simple basis:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/email_tunnels.service
[Unit]
Description=E-mail and HTTP tunnels over SSH
Documentation=https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465353/5132

[Service]
User=cal
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -N -D5080 -Llocalhost:10110:xx.xx.xx.xx:110 -Llocalhost:10025:xx.xx.xx.xx:25 tunnels@xx.xx.xx.xx
RestartSec=120

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then you merely need to ensure that this service is run after your home directory, containing your SSH identity files, is available.  Of course, with some setups this is only the case *after you have logged in* and your home directory has been auto-mounted, decrypted, and whatnot.  In which case you might as well not set up a system-level service *at all* and instead run this as a user service under your per-user instance of systemd, which is started at your first login:

```
# /home/cal/.config/systemd/user/email_tunnels.service
[Unit]
Description=E-mail and HTTP tunnels over SSH
Documentation=https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465353/5132

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -N -D5080 -Llocalhost:10110:xx.xx.xx.xx:110 -Llocalhost:10025:xx.xx.xx.xx:25 tunnels@xx.xx.xx.xx
RestartSec=120

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Use the `--user` option to `systemctl` to control such a per-user service, of course.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200281/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  [*The systemd House of Horror*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/).  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408848/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). *[Don't abuse su for dropping user privileges](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dont-abuse-su-for-dropping-privileges.html)*. Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132
- [Why can't systemd service access user's home dir, but works after service restart?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426229/)

Comment: _"Of course, with some setups this is only the case after you have logged in and your home directory has been auto-mounted, decrypted"_ .... **Dwaarrrrggghh**!!!! My home directory *IS* encrypted.... dammit, how could I forget/overlook that detail?!!!!!